# How to iterate through HTMLCollection in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

to get all links on the page. We need to modify a few.

if I console log links, I get an HTMLCollection of 100+ a elements.
If I console log links.length, it's 0.

I've tried everything I can find to convert this to an array but nothing is working.

`Array.from(links)`

`Array.prototype.slice.call(links)`

`[].forEach.call(links, function (el) {...});`

`HTMLCollection.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator];`

`HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;`

These all produce an empty array.

Additionally `var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');` produces an empty NodeList.

I've run out of options. The initial links variable is very much not empty. So I don't understand why all of these suggested options don't work. Additionally, jQuery is not an option for us.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue at stacksnippets?

Comment: [All of these work fine.](https://jsfiddle.net/tL9dmjqs/1/) Your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this works for me

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var result = [].slice.call(links)
```

Comment: by the way your listed other options work as well, are you sure your problem is not in other place?

Comment: I had to move my code to the footer, which does not make a ton of sense to me. It was able to find all the links, so why not iterate through them? unless the code is in the footer area...

Answer (score 6):

```js
Array.from(HTML_COLLECTION).forEach(function (element) {
  console.log(element);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use an EventListener

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  console.log(links);
}
```

O

Answer (score 0):

Almost had it: `var linksAsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(links, 0)`

Also, as an alternative, you can write a helper function to avoid needing to convert nodelists to arrays all of the time. For example,

```
function each(elems, fn){
  var i = -1;
  while(++i < elems.length){
    fn(elems[i])
  }
}

each(links, function(link){ console.log(link); })
```