# Failing to convert HTMLCollection and NodeList to array using proven methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I'm using react-pdf which creates HTML based on the PDF document passed to it. There is a  (for each PDF page) with 50+  (each line of text) nested into it which I need to parse the text of.

The goal is use this to "element.scrollIntoView()" when a specific string is found.

There seems to be 2 options for me to get the elements, an HTMLCollection and a NodeList.
Currently I get an HTMLCollection by doing:

```
const spanElementCollection = page.getElementsByTagName("span");
```

[image: Which shows the full HTMLCollection]

I've found numerous resources recommending that I use Array.from(HTMLCollection) to convert to an array so I can parse it. After converting, the array is *always* empty.

`const spanElements = Array.from(spanElementCollection);`

[image: Empty array after conversion]

Additionally, I've tried converting this to an array from a NodeList using `const spanElementList = await page.querySelectorAll('div.textLayer > span');` which always returns an empty NodeList similar to the above screenshot.

Removing `> span` from querySelectorAll works to get the parent `<div>`, but I cannot get the ~50 NodeList `<span>` children into an array.

[image: const spanElementList = await page.querySelectorAll('div.textLayer'); returns]

All of this is being called from within an `inputRef(() => {})` [as recommended by the developer of the package](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/issues/271#issuecomment-562880789)

I've already viewed the closes adjacent issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409831/how-to-iterate-through-htmlcollection-in-javascript)

Comment: This suggests that the HTML elements are populated *after* you create the HTML collection with `getElementsByTagName`. Please make sure you only execute your code (to create an array, or to use another method) when the document is fully loaded with all relevent HTML elements.

Comment: @trincot I believe you're correct and that dawned on me shortly after writing all of this out (the true magic of writing a stackoverflow post). I changed my approach, but I think implementing a useEffect would fix the problem entirely.